# How do I add a new element to an existing class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already generated a class by "script/generate model blah blah1:string"

How would I add a "blah2:string" to the existing model? Is there a script or do I have to manually edit the database and every file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create migration:

```
./script/generate migration AddBlah2ToBlah blah2:string
```

This will create migration in db/migrate ruby file with migration - you can check if it correctly added column to table. Then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

or in production environment:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will add column to your database and you can use it in Rails:

```
@blah = Blah.first
@blah.blah2 = "new string"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new migration of change table.. [Check this.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). See section 3.2

Comment: I read that, I'm not sure where I enter the code. Do I create a new file with the code in it and execute it with Ruby?

Comment: Create a migration and your code in that migration. Run the rake task to execute it